# Websphere CPU usage

Tags: websphere, cpu

I am experiencing the following phenomenon in WebSphere:
I have a multi threaded process on a multicore machine, but when I see the CPU consumption it appears two CPUs are in use of 100%. The two others are not in use at all.

How is this determined? Can it be tuned by WebSphere? Is it something in my AIX os?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this for more info on troubleshooting 100% CPU kind of problems

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21052641
Look at collecting data manually.

Analysing the collected data would help you understand what is happening.

have a look at this thread too
[How does Java makes use of multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436422/how-java-makes-use-of-multiple-cores)

HTH

Manglu