# How to use multiple cores with java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand how java threads works with CPU cores. I have a 4 core CPU and when I try to run below codes execution times are interesting. Why it doesn't speed up with multiple threads? Am I doing something wrong?

availableProcessors() returns 4 by the way.

Below code takes nearly 27 seconds;

```
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int x = 0;
            while(x < 10000000){
                System.out.println(x);
                x++;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);

    t1.start();
```

When I use multiple threads it takes 33 seconds;

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int x = 0;
            while(x < 5000000){
                System.out.println(x);
                x++;
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int x = 5000000;
            while(x < 10000000){
                System.out.println(x);
                x++;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);

    t1.start();


    Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable2);

    t2.start();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Java make use of multiple cores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436422/how-does-java-makes-use-of-multiple-cores)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has a sequential bottleneck which is printing to the terminal.

`System.out.println` has a synchronized block in it and hence writes are one at a time, and hence your code is not parallel.

Sequential parts (including coordination) of the program is what governs its performance according to [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)